# Weka unknown datatype

Tags: mysql, database, weka, data-mining

I'm trying to import a database form mysql to weka, but the problem is that even after the database is loaded and displayed, when I click ok so I can start working whit the database, the message "unknown data type: INT" appears.  I've tried modifying the DatabaseUtil.props file but nothing seems to work, so I really preacite if someone could tell me how to solve this issue once for all.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try when editing the props file?

Comment: I removed the comment from the int datatype

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the comment from the `int` datatype lines in the prop file, or take the mysql prop file included, add:

`INT=5`

Since 5 is the identifier for `int` types, then rename the mysql props file to `DatabaseUtil.props`

Comment: I've already removed the comment in the prop file, tried the same thing using the mysql props file and even the mysqlsever 2005 file but again nothing seems to work, I appreciate if you can tell me what else can I do. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors other than the 'Unknown data type' message?

Answer (score 0):

Put just, without semicolons or others characters

> INT=5